# Tower is giving me a weird error message

Tags: git, git-tower

I added a submodule in the wrong directory in Tower.  So I removed it and am trying to add it in the correct subfolder.  When I paste in the url of the submodule, Tower tells me "The destination path for the submodule already exists."  But it doesn't exist.  What is going on with Tower?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by doing step #2 on this stackoverflow answer of [how to remove a git submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260748/how-do-i-remove-a-git-submodule), and then by typing in the directory name that I wanted it to create to store the submodule in.